# Storybook requires react, but i use Angular

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I have Angular app and storybook in it. After migration storybook to 7.5.3 version, it requires react, react-dom for dependencies. Is it ok? As it's weird for me.

[https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#react-peer-dependencies-required](https://stackoverflow.com)
React peer dependencies required
Has automigration

Starting in 7.0, react and react-dom are now required peer dependencies of Storybook when using addon-docs (or docs via addon-essentials).

Storybook uses react in a variety of docs-related packages. In the past, we've done various trickery hide this from non-React users. However, with stricter peer dependency handling by npm8, npm, and yarn pnp those tricks have started to cause problems for those users. Rather than resorting to even more complicated tricks, we are making react and react-dom required peer dependencies.

To upgrade manually, add any version of react and react-dom as devDependencies using your package manager of choice, e.g.

```
npm add react react-dom --dev
```

Comment: Yes, it's fine. React is the ui shell that hosts the angular components when you run storybook locally

Comment: Yes, because storybook need dependencies from react, bacause storybook running with ```react```, and now you should run
```npm install react react-dom```, when you done install this dependencies you can run ```npm run storybook```